# Number of k-cycles from an adjacency matrix of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

Let $G(V,E)$ be a finite undirected graph with an adjacency matrix $A$. As far as I know it holds that that $A^k_{ii}$ gives us the number of walks starting and ending at vertex $i$ and having length $k$ (note that $A^k$ is the $k$-th power of the adjacency matrix).

From this we can find a number of sub-graphs isomorphic to $C_3$ (cycle of length $3$) as $\frac{tr(A^3)}{6}$. My intuition is that each $C_3$ has 3 vertices and there are $2$ directions we can take to complete the cycle, thus we count each cycle $3 \cdot 2 = 6$ times.

Now I'm thinking if there is a general formula that would allow us to determine a number of $C_k$s in a graph given it's adjacency matrix?

And also a weaker version: What is the formula for $C_4$?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no known polynomial time algorithm to count the number of $C_k$'s for arbitrary $k$ (it is a #P-hard problem).  Therefore, I wouldn't expect to find a simple formula for arbitrary $k$, as otherwise it would lead to a polynomial time algorithm.  It works for triangles since walks are also cycles, but even for $C_4$ you face the problem of counting walks of the type $a, b, a, b, a$.  Although I guess for $C_4$ you could take $tr(A^4)$ and divide by the number of $P_3$s.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Could you please hint how would you calculate $C_4$? I'm not sure how to do this from your description. I also thought about the $a,b,a,b,a$ problem and was thinking about $\frac{tr(A^4) - tr(A^2)}{8}$ to get rid of the walks that return to the starting vertex immediately. But I still need to work it out bc the above formula is obviously not correct.

Comment: So, $tr(A^4)$ counts legit $C_4$'s, which are of the form $abcda$, but also walks of the form $abaca$ ($b = c$ possible), and $abcba$.  The number of $abaca$ is $deg(a)^2$.  Summing over all $a$'s, this is $\sum_{a \in V} deg(a)^2$.  I don't know any clean matrix way to express this, but maybe there is.  The number of $abcba$ is the number of paths on three vertices.  The latter is the sum of non-diagonal entries in $A^2$, which is $\sum_{ij} A_{ij}^2 - tr(A^2)$.  The number of $C_4$ should be $tr(A^4) - \sum_{a \in V} deg(a)^2 - (\sum_{ij} A_{ij}^2) - tr(A^2))$.  Please backcheck.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I don't think that $sum_{a\in V} deg(a)^2$ gives the correct number of $abaca$. For example for path of length $2$ ($2$ edges) it gives $6$.

Comment: If you count the $b = c$ as a possibility, it should be ok.  For the example of the path of length two, name the vertices $u, v, w$ with edges $uv, vw$.  Then there are indeed 6 walks, which are walks are $uvuvu$, $vuvuv$, $vuvwv$, $vwvwv$, $vwvuv$, and $wvwvw$.  The idea of $deg(a)^2$ is that you have $deg(a)$ ways of leaving $a$, one way to go back, then $deg(a)$ ways to leave $a$ again, and one way to get back again.